# Null value returned in getter

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have created a simple program that will ask the user for their username and everything was working correctly until the point of the authentication. I have manually inserted data into the database for testing purposes and now I want to authenticate the login of a user by checking if they have entered the corresponding username as the same one on the database. However, I am being returned a null value when I ask for the getters of the administrator object.

Can someone please help me on why null is being returned whilst data is in the database? Thank you.

For reference purposes:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //objects for connection

            //Testing 
              Administrator cevo = new Administrator();
            //==========================================//
            Session session = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            if (username.getText().equals(cevo.getGivenName())) { //Returned Value is Null, but data is present in DB.
                System.out.println("MATCH");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(cevo.getGivenName());
                System.out.println(username.getText());
                System.out.println("NO MATCH");
            }
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }

    });

}
```

---

---

This is my Administrator class, for reference purposes:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "ADMINISTRATOR", schema = "registrationsystem")
public class Administrator  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JoinColumn(name ="ID", nullable = false)
    protected int ID;


    @Column(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "FAMILYNAME")
    //@OneToOne(mappedBy = "familyname", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected String familyName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "AGE")
    //@OneToOne(mappedBy = "age", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected int age;

    @JoinColumn(name = "OCCUPATION")
   // @OneToOne(mappedBy = "occupation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Occupation occupation;

    public Administrator() {
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
        this.name = givenName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Occupation getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(Occupation occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct however I believe with hibernate is it possible to use getters and setters to retrieve data from a database, since hibernate requires a zero argument constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be a bit confusing, since you dont actually query for anything in the database.

```
Administrator cevo = new Administrator();

if (username.getText().equals(cevo.getGivenName())) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

It is obvious that `cevo.getGivenName()` is returning null, since it does not have been initialised yet. Just because you call a method from an arbitary object inside a transaction does not mean that it will automatically fetch your corresponding database object. Hibernate is feature-rich, but in the end it is not magic.

You should try to query for an Administrator. Here are some hints:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select Administrator where id = :admin_id");
query.setParameter("admin_id", 1);
Administrator result = (Administrator) query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely give a try and see if the application does succeed. I really appreciate the support.

Comment: You have to adapt the query a little bit to your requirements tough. I hope that this helped you! If you have any other questions, feel free to ask, otherwise you could mark this as answer.